# create a drilldown menu 

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div called `subMenuRigth` this div it's inside a `<li>` what i want to accomplish is that div appears beside of the the div called `subMenu` i tried in very differents ways to make it but it's doesn't work, it's nevers shows the contains.

**this is my html**

```
<div id="menu" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
    <label class="formatText" id="lblIndicators">Tal</label>
    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e menuIcon" style="float:right"></span>
    <div id="subMenu" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
        <ul class="options">
            <li>
                <label class="formatText">SubTal</label>
                <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s" style="float:right"></span>
                <div id="subMenuRight" class="ui-accordion-header ui-helper-reset ui-state-default ui-corner-all">
                    <ul class=options>
                        <li>hi</li>
                        <li>bye</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li>algo</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

**this my css**

```
#menu
{
    width:150px;
}
#subMenu
{
    display:none;
    width:149px;
}

#subMenuRight
{
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    float:rigth;
}
```

**my js**

```
$(document).ready(initialize);

function initialize(){

    $("#menu").hover(mouseIn,mouseOut);
    $(".options li").hover(overOption,outOption);
    $(".subMenu").hover(openRigthMenu,closeRigthMenu);
}

function mouseIn(){
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','');
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-s');
    $("#subMenu").slideDown(100);
}

function mouseOut(){
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','');
    $(this).find('span').attr('class','ui-icon ui-icon-triangle-1-e');
    $("#subMenu").fadeOut(100);
}

function overOption(){
    $(this).attr('class','ui-state-hover ui-corner-all');
}

function outOption(){
    $(this).attr('class','');
}

function openRigthMenu(){
    $("#subMenuRight").css('display','block');
    $("#subMenuRight").css('outline','0');
    $("#subMenuRight").slideDown(100);
}

function closeRegithMenu(){
    $("#subMenuRight").slideUp(100);
}
```

[My live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guukV/1/)

Comment: +1 for a well put together question with plenty of code and a live example.

Comment: Since you are using `jQuery`, have you considered using a plugin for your menu?

Comment: is `float:rigth`, in the CSS, a typo?

Comment: It looks like there are multiple instances where the word "right" is spelled incorrectly

Comment: Sorry but i''m already tried and doesn't solve my problem

Comment: actually there were like 50 typos O_O

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After typo fixing:

```
#subMenuRight
{
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    left:100%;
    top:0px;
}

.options{
    position:relative;
}
```

and the result was..... (drum roll)

http://jsfiddle.net/ZxvkN/

it was rigth! ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can view the working example at: http://jsfiddle.net/CyjfU/

The solution essentially requires two parts: 1) css styling; 2) modified structured;

**CSS:**

```
#subMenu
{
    display:none;
    width:149px;
    position: relative;
}

#subMenuRight
{
    display:none;
    width:150px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;    
    left: 150px;
}
```

The key with the css is establishing the positioning of the elements.  The first positioning to establish is that of `#subMenu`.  You want to set the position to `position: relative;`.  The second part is with the `#subMenuRight`.  You want to set the position to that to `position: absolute;` (if parent was not set to relative then this setting would default to the nearest parent property -- which doesn't currently exist so it would be positioned as `absolute` to the body.  You will also want to establish the position of the absolute element by declaring `top: 0px; left: 150px;`.  This sets the top position to 0px to align the top edges and indents the left by 150px.

The structure portion contains two parts: a) HTML; b) JavaScript

**HTML:**

Added the class `subSubMenu` to the `li` containing your true sub-menu.

**JavaScript:**

Changed: `$(".subMenu").hover(openRigthMenu,closeRigthMenu);` to `$(".subSubMenu").hover(openRightMenu,closeRightMenu);`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working example after modifying your original live demo: [working live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/guukV/4/)

First off you are accessing your subMenu in javascript by class instead of by id.  I then updated the CSS a little to get the positioning correct.

Answer (score 0):

There's a few things that aren't really clear. For example, will you have more than 1 submenuRight. Also, if you want it to be besides the subMenu's class div, why is it nested so deeply in the tree hierarchy?.

Nonetheless, to get back to what you want to achieve you could add the following:

```
#subMenu {
  position: relative;
}

#subMenuRight {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
}
```

This would fix it but I don't think this is exactly what you are looking for, as if you have more than one submenuright, they would all be stacked on top of each other. Maybe you should create a sibling to subMenu where you would put all your subMenuRight items?

One other answer could be to change your subMenu to a `<ul>` tag, and inside create a `<li>` with 2 divs, 1 being the content, the other, your subMenuRight.

Comment: Oh I didn't see the link for the live demo, also, I'm not sure my answer is relevant, I can delete this answer if this is not relevant.